# Flutter - Using as to cast list of timestamps not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

```
Map<String, dynamic> mapOfObjects; 
dates = mapOfObjects['dates'] as List<Timestamp>;
```

mapOfObjects looks like this:

```
{requiredCompletions: 0, totalCompletions: 0, incentive: [{rewardAmt: 0, rewardId: }], habitType: 1, id: , habitNotifications: false, dates: [Timestamp(seconds=1618903800, nanoseconds=0)], habitDescription: }
```

I am running this under a FutureBuilder that is fetching from Firebase, and it is getting hung up on the dates. I can specify the index by doing the following:

```
date = mapOfObjects['dates'][0] as Timestamp;
```

and it works perfectly fine. Why isn't the `as` casting working?

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore It is not casting the List to a List of Timestamps, when I am expecting it to.

Comment: Why would you expect that? Please clarify your whole question.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore If `mapOfObjects['dates']` is a type that is a List, and `mapOfObjects['dates'][0]`, which is an index of that list that same list, is a Timestamp and within Firestore the field type of 'dates' is a timestamp as well. Why would the casting of the type List<Timestamp> not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
dates = List<Timestamp>.from(mapOfObjects['dates'] as List);
```